# imprimindo lixo de memoria dentro do vetor

Tags: c

Boa tarde pessoal, estou começando a aprender C na faculdade, tenho um trabalho para fazer onde eu devo criar um código para registrar 5 livros diferentes(nome, autor, editora) e gerar um código automaticamente. O código devera ter um menu para o usuário escolher a opção que deseja (0 sair, 1 cadastrar novo livro, 2 visualizar livros ja cadastrados). Pois bem, o meu problema esta no item 2 do meu menu, na hora de mostrar para o usuário os livros ja cadastrados, se eu cadastro os livros eles aparecem normal, porem se eu escolher a opção de mostrar os livros ja cadastrados nao tendo nenhum livro cadastrado ainda aparece lixo de memoria em 2 entradas do meu vetor, o vetor tem tamanho 5, o problema esta ocorrendo somente nas entradas 1 e 2, as entradas 0, 3 e 4 esta aparecendo "A entrada [x] esta vazia!" como deveria.

Gostaria de saber se alguém pode me ajudar corrigir isso e me explicar o porque disso estar acontecendo, e somente em 2 entradas, segue a baixo meu código.

Obrigado des de ja.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <locale.h>

struct produto
{
    int codigo;
    char nome[51];
    char autor[51];
    char editora[21];
};

int aleatorio ()
{
    int i;
    int x;
    int codigo;

    srand(time(NULL));
    x = rand() % 9999;
    codigo = x;

    return codigo;
};

int main()
{   
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Portuguese");
    struct produto livro[5];
    int opcao;
    int tamanho;
    int i;
    int x;
    int cod;
    char name[51];
    char author[51];
    char publisher[21];

    i = 0;
    x = 0;
    opcao = 3;

    while(opcao != 0)
    {
        printf("\n\n\n");
        printf("\t Escolha uma das opcoes: \n");
        printf("\t 1 - Cadastrar novo livro \n");
        printf("\t 2 - Visualizar livros cadastrados \n");
        printf("\t 0 - Sair \n");
        printf("\n\n\n");
        scanf("\t %d", &opcao);
        system("cls");
        switch(opcao)
        {
            case 0: // Encerar
                system("cls");
                exit(0);
                break;
            case 1: // inserir novo cadastro
                if (i == 5)
                {       
                    printf("\t Sistema de cadastro lotado. Não é possível armazenar mais informações! \n");
                    system("pause");
                    system("cls");
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    printf("\t Insira o nome do Livro: ");
                    scanf("%s", &name);
                    strcpy(livro[i].nome,name);
                    printf("\n");
                    fflush(stdin);

                    printf("\t Insira o nome do Autor: ");
                    scanf(" %s", &author);
                    strcpy(livro[i].autor,author);
                    printf("\n");
                    fflush(stdin);

                    printf("\t Insira o nome do Editora: ");
                    scanf(" %s", &publisher);
                    strcpy(livro[i].editora,publisher);
                    printf("\n");
                    fflush(stdin);

                    cod = aleatorio();
                    livro[i].codigo = cod;
                    printf("\t O codigo do livro registrado e: %d \n \n", livro[i].codigo);
                    printf("\t Livro cadastrado com Sucesso! \n");
                    system("pause");
                    system("cls");
                    i++;
                    break;
                }
            case 2: // mostrar todas as entradas
                for (x=0; x<=4; x++)
                {
                    tamanho=strlen(livro[x].nome);
                    if(tamanho == 0)
                    {
                        printf("\t\t A entrada %d esta vazia! \n", x+1);
                        fflush(stdin);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        printf("\n");
                        printf("\t Entrada %d", x+1);
                        printf("\t Livro: %s\n", livro[x].nome);
                        printf("\t Autor: %s\n", livro[x].autor);
                        printf("\t Editora: %s\n", livro[x].editora);
                        printf("\t Codigo: %d\n ", livro[x].codigo);
                        printf("\n\n"); 
                    }
                }
                system("pause");
                system("cls");
                break;
            default:
                printf("\n\n");
                printf("\t Opcao invalida \n");
                system("pause");
                system("cls");
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Você não inicializou seu array com nome sendo uma string de comprimento zero, dessa forma ao listar todo o array estará pegando lixo de memória. Sem inicializar todo o array você pode contornar isso limitando a exibição apenas dos itens já cadastrados, que você controla utilizando a variável i.

Comment: Obrigado  pela resposta. Você disse "não inicializou seu array com nome sendo uma string" será que poderia me explicar melhor? e será que poderia me explicar como eu faço para isso? pois preciso mostrar que a posição esta vazia, nao apenas mostrar as que ja foram cadastradas.

Comment: for (i=0; i<5; i++)
livro[i].nome[0] = '\0';

ou:
for (i=0; i<5; i++)
strcpy(livro[i].nome, "");

Comment: Otimo! funcionou !!!
Muito obrigado!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Olá, pelo que vi faltou inicializar o array `livro[]`, como está testando se o `nome` foi preenchido, podes fazer um loop no inicio para limpar o lixo neste campo, exemplo:

```
for (x=0; x<=4; x++)
    livro[x].nome[0] = 0;
```

ou

```
for (x=0; x<=4; x++)
    memset(livro[x].nome, 0, sizeof(produto.nome));
```

Abraço

Comment: Muito obrigado pela resposta :D